# How to detect small bullet holes from low quality image - OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

For the overview of project, I'm creating a project for real bullets simulator. A person is shooting a screen(a white plastic sheet for projector) with real guns, behind the screen there is a camera
which is detecting every new bullet holes from the images of screen.
I've tried many method for this purpose, also i will appreciate a new idea until unless I'm getting accuracy in detecting bullets.

Here is the main code what i have tried.

Here is the original images which is capturing by camera behind the screen
[image: sample_plate.png]

And here is another manipulated image which is for specify what result I'm expecting. 
[image: Click here]

I want to detect these original bullet hole and draw a circle on them
this is what I've tried using open `cv2.threshold` method

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

## getting bullet shots images
image = cv2.imread("sample_plate.png")

## applying threshold
retval, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(image, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite("thres_binary_result.png",threshold_image)

retval, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(image, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)
cv2.imwrite("thres_trunc_result.png",threshold_image)

retval, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(image, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
cv2.imwrite("thres_tozero_result.png",threshold_image)
```

And here is the result images what i got.

cv2.THRESH_BINARY : 
[image: thres_binary_result.png]

cv2.THRESH_TRUNC : 
[image: thres_trunc_result]

cv2.THRESH_TOZERO : 
[image: thres_tozero_result.png]

Please suggest any new method and please have a try on my images,
I've tried many answer and they can't help me because on the screen(white plastic sheet for projector) there is a video playing and I have to detect real bullets hole on it, so there is not a chance to detect from before and after frame because every frame will be different, whether there is new shot or not.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It appears the setup is fundamentally flawed. You're trying to use an optical approach when the optical signal is not at all under your control. Software isn't going to fix that, I fear. It might be better to fix the sensor setup. Moving outside the visible spectrum might be a more reliable approach - either to IR or to UV.

Comment: Another hardware approach would be a second screen behind the first. The first one shows the projected image; the second one is illuminated from the other side and just shows the bullet holes.

Comment: @MSalters Yes I can go for another hardware approach, Tell me what is position going to be for IR light, is it going to be with camera or other side (with projector)?

Comment: Hard to predict what works best. It depends on too many factors.Just try both and look at the camera images yourself.

Comment: rule #1 in image-processing: crap in -> crap out . get a proper camera, get some tension on your screen (I'm sure you can do better that this rag). use backgroud illumination or make sure it is dark behind the illuminated screen. you have to generate some contrast. don't waste another second on processing this material

Comment: Thresholding won't work in your case since some holes have a very high intensity (like in the illuminated center) and some have very low intensity (bottom left corner). You will have to change your setup if you want to solve this using thresholding methods.

Comment: Yes i tried changing my setup, and got the perfect result. Thanks, All these comments was really helpful. @MSalters